Can I ensure a ground state gap for a Hamiltonian in a finite Hilbert space based on a truncated absolutely convergent expansion?
The setup:
Consider the Hamiltonian $H(\epsilon)$ acting on a Hilbert space of dimension $M$. Assume an expansion series that is absolutely convergent for $\epsilon\leq \epsilon_c$ with $\epsilon_c\neq 0$:
\begin{equation}
    H(\epsilon)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\epsilon^iH_i
\end{equation}
Now consider the truncated Hamiltonian to order $n$
\begin{equation}
    H^\prime_n(\epsilon):=\sum_{i=0}^n\epsilon^iH_i.
\end{equation}
Assume the ground state of $H^\prime_n(\epsilon)$ is unique for $0< \epsilon \leq \epsilon_u$, note that it could be degenerate at exactly $\epsilon=0$.
Question:
Is the ground state of $H(\epsilon)$ (the full Hamiltonian) guaranteed to be also unique for sufficiently small (but $\neq0$) $\epsilon$?
Ideas: My intuition is that there should be a way to construct a continuity argument on a disk around $\epsilon=0$ that allows me to connect the low energy eigenstates of $H(\epsilon)$ with the ones of $H^\prime_n(\epsilon)$. Indeed Hal Tasaki proves this in the case only the second order terms contribute. This is done in Lemma 10.1 of his book, but I want to study the more general case for arbitrary $n$.
The book: "Tasaki, H. (2020). Half-Filled Models: Lieb’s Theorems and the Origin of Antiferromagnetism and Ferrimagnetism. In: Physics and Mathematics of Quantum Many-Body Systems. Graduate Texts in Physics. Springer, Cham. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-41265-4_10"
